# Change Woocommerce New Order Email text in certain conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In woocommerce, when a user makes an order it sends the new order notification to the Admin and the template file if `yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php` and it has the following code block

```
 /**
  * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

 <p><?php printf( __( 'You have received an order from %s. The order is as follows:', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ); ?></p>

 <?php
 /**
  * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
  * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

and I want to change text

`<p><?php printf( __( 'You have received an order from %s. The order is as follows:', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ); ?></p>`

in certain conditions. I can trigger the condition as follow,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'my_own_function',  1, 1  );
function my_own_function( $order_id )
{
    if( certain_condition )
    {
         // change the text <p><?php printf( __( 'You have received an order from %s. The order is as follows:', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ); ?></p>
     }
}
```

is there any way to change the text.

Comment: The only way is to embed that conditions in if/else statements directly overriding the template `yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php` … You can't use hooks for that.

Comment: Yes this could solve my problem